# Deep linking to android or web

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, deep-linking

I'm trying to add some Facebook meta tags to my web page so it can be shared on Facebook. I also want the following functionality:

- when web users click the facebook share they see the webpage in their browser;
- when mobile users click the share:

  - if they have my app installed they are taken to content in the app
  - if they DON'T have the app they are taken to the Google Play store to download it.

So basically I want mobile users to use my app when they click the shared link, meanwhile for web users a web page is displayed where they can learn about the app.

What I've tryed so far(as example I've used imdb):

```
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Imdb - Android app"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="game"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="Download the app to see the content"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://.../pic.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="690" />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="361" />

    <meta property="al:android:package" content="com.imdb.mobile" />
    <meta property="al:android:url" content="imdb://title/tt0117500" />
    <meta property="al:android:app_name" content="IMDb Movies & TV" />  
    <meta property="al:web:url" content="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.imdb.mobile" />
```

Unfortunately, when mobile users click share with tags above, only the web page is displayed(they are not redirected to app store if they don't have the app).

Comment: I have noticed that I had installed Facebook Lite on my phone and not the full Facebook app. The "og" tags above do not work in FB Lite version, but they do work in the full Facebook app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook has not done a good job of supporting their App Links standard. It doesn't work at all on iOS anymore, and is inconsistent on Android.

As a workaround, you can put an automatic JS redirect to the Play Store on the page where you host these App Links tags. This will have the same basic effect, and is the approach we use for the [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team) mobile link routing platform.

Comment: In my tests, automatic JS redirect does not work in mobile browser(Chrome & Samsung browsers): it either opens the web page verrsion of GPlay(not the native app) or does not work at all. The only way I could open the native GPlay is if I make the user click somewhere in the page. At branch.io did you guys manage to make it work seamlessly? If it works for you maybe I can use branch.io.

Comment: Hmmm...maybe we did have to add something extra for Chrome (which uses Chrome Intents rather than URI schemes). Trying Branch might be worth it anyway — it's free and has a bunch of other useful features!